# MAMP 4.4 - Installing additional PHP versions failed

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

Just installed MAMP 4.4, but when trying to install additional versions of PHP, I keep getting the same error:

"The update could not be validated. Please make sure that you are using a secure network and try again."

I've tried this on both work networks and from home and keep getting the same message, has anyone else had this problem?  or any advice on how to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue. Luckily they updated to 4.4.1 to resolve the issue. MAMP itself didn't notice the upgrade but if you download MAMP from the website, it's version 4.4.1.

Additionally you can download the PHP versions manually on the mamp website, [here](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/), and then unzip to the /Applications/MAMP/bin/php folder.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing to resolve the issue, but I also removed all my old "archived" versions before opening 4.4.1 or 4.4 (9593) just to make sure it wasn't some old setting that was being brought across wrong.

Comment: When I tried to open the 4.4.1 package I downloaded, I got this error: 

The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.installer.pagecontroller error -1.)
Couldn't open "MAMP_MAMP_PRO_4.4.1.pkg".

Comment: this did not work for me. I have MAMP Pro v 4.4.1 and am still running into the same error.